# Is there any advantage of using X-Robot-Tag instead of robots.txt?

Tags: http, web, http-headers, robots.txt

It looks like there are two mainstream solutions for instructing crawlers what to index and what not to index: adding an X-Robot-Tag HTTP header, or indicating a robots.txt.

Is there any advantage to using the former?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `robots.txt` you cannot disallow indexing of your documents.

They have different purposes:

- `robots.txt` can disallow **crawling** (with `Disallow`)
- `X-Robots-Tag` ¹ can disallow **indexing** (with `noindex`)

(And both offer additional different features, e.g., [linking to your Sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14218476/1591669) in `robots.txt`, [disallowing following links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/89518/17633) in `X-Robots-Tag`, and many more.)

*Crawling* means accessing the document. *Indexing* means providing a link to (and possibly metadata from or about) the document in an index. In the typical case, a bot indexes a document after having crawled it, but that’s not necessary.

A bot that isn’t allowed to crawl a document may still index it (without ever accessing it). A bot that isn’t allowed to index a document may still crawl it. [You can’t disallow both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524993/1591669).

¹ Note that the header is called `X-Robots-Tag`, not `X-Robot-Tag`. By the way, the metadata name `robots` (for the HTML `meta` element) is an alternative to the HTTP header.