# What happens when a denied page (robots) is still in sitemap.xml?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, sitemap, robots.txt, sitemap.xml

I want to prevent a page from being indexed, along with its assets (images).

So if I tell crawlers to skip that page, but that page is still registered in sitemap.xml, will any information on that page be indexed?

Comment: Depends. On how you actually “tell crawlers to skip that page”, whether you specified how those external assets are to be index separately, whether or not a specific crawler wants to respect your instructions, etc. pp.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt disallows [*crawling*, not *indexing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657571/1591669).

If you disallow crawling of a URL in your robots.txt, and you list this URL in your sitemap, it is still disallowed to be crawled. Occurrence in a sitemap doesn’t change this.

This URL might still be indexed, though (whether it’s in the sitemap or not).

Comment: you need to fetch a page in order to index it. if it is disallowed by the robots directives, then it won't be indexed. Not all crawlers follow robots.txt though

Comment: @JulienNioche: Nope, you can index a URL (not a page) without fetching the page. Many search engines (including Google Search) do this. You will then typically see a notice like "The site’s robots.txt doesn’t allow us to crawl this page, that is why we can’t show you a description". They might even show a title, taken from hyperlink anchors that linked to it.

Comment: you're right, I hadn't considered that aspect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answer, you can use the *Noindex* directive in your robots.txt file. It is not part of the standard AFAIK but is commonly used, see [blog](https://www.deepcrawl.com/blog/best-practice/robots-txt-noindex-the-best-kept-secret-in-seo/) - although there seem to be diverging opinions about it. Alternatively, you could use [the robots meta tags](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in your webpages.

As usual, there is no guarantee that all crawlers will respect the robots directives, however the main ones will.