# How to block subdomain used for URL shortening service with robots.txt?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, url-shortener, nofollow, noindex

Let’s say my domain is `example.com`. On `www.example.com`, I had set up my main website (set up with Blogger) and used `go.example.com` for URL shortening (setup with GoDaddy Shortened Service). Now, I want to block all `go.example.com` URLs so that they can't be indexed.

If I use `rel="noindex,nofollow"` for `go.example.com` URLs in my main blog, then, does this affect my blog search engine optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this robots.txt on `go.example.com`, you disallow conforming bots to *crawl* any URL from that host:

```
# https://go.example.com/
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

If you are fine with *crawling*, but you want to prevent *indexing* ([you can’t have both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524993/1591669)), you have to use `noindex` (either in the `meta`-`robots` element or in the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`). Note that you can’t use `noindex` as link type in the `rel` attribute.

That said, if you always redirect (e.g., with 301) from `go.example.com` to the canonical URL (on another host), search engine bots have no reason to index your document on `go.example.com`, as you don’t provide any content, only the redirect.